# Heilige Hooleh?

Tags: words, song-poetry, music

What is [this](http://www.jewishsonglyrics.com/2014/01/8th-day-hooleh.html) *holy hooleh* that *8th Day* are singing about?

Comment: I think they made it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At [VideoStatic](http://www.videostatic.com/watch-it/2014/03/10/8th-day-hooleh-chaim-marcus-dir) I found the following:

> 8th Day "Hooleh!" (Chaim Marcus, dir.)
>
> The Whole Mishpocha.
>
> 8th day is fronted by brothers Shmuel and Bentzi. The video was
>   directed by their brother, Chaim.
>
> The band first made a splash with a video that was featured on
>   Videostatic, called "Ya'alili", directed by Larry Guterman (Antz, Cats
>   & Dogs).
>
> The Song
>
> The song is called **"hooleh!" from Yiddish slang meaning something
>   like "forget-all-your-issues-just-radiate joy".**

Videostatic says it is the world's leading source for music video news and community. It does not claim to be an authority on Yiddish slang.